# Group by column but return dataframe as the initial one - pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas dataframe looking like this:

| id | attr1 | attr2 | attr3 | label |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 2 or less | category1 | other_cat1 | 2 |
| 45 | between 3 and 4 | category3 | other_cat3 | 7 |
| 123 | 2 or less | category1 | other_cat1 | 2 |
| 76 | 5 or more | category4 | other_cat4 | 9 |
| 45 | between 3 and 4 | category3 | other_cat3 | 7 |
| 123 | 2 or less | category1 | other_cat1 | 1 |

What I want to have is a resulting dataframe with the same columns but the labels to be grouped by the id counts.
I have done this:

```
df.groupby(['label'])['id'].count().reset_index()
```

which results of course in the following :

| label | id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 7 | 2 |
| 9 | 1 |

The goal is to have the following:

| id | attr1 | attr2 | attr3 | label | counts |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 2 or less | category1 | other_cat1 | 2 | 2 |
| 45 | between 3 and 4 | category3 | other_cat3 | 7 | 2 |
| 76 | 5 or more | category4 | other_cat4 | 9 | 1 |
| 123 | 2 or less | category1 | other_cat1 | 1 | 1 |

The attr1, attr2, attr3 are **always the same** per **id**. Only the label value may differ per id. Thus, my problem can be summarized in the existence of multiple identical rows and I thought that I could group them like that in order to make it more concise.

I can't use the pandas [transform](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) method because I don't want the returning dataframe to have the same shape as the initial one. I can't use the pandas [aggregate](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.aggregate.html) method because I need to have all the columns as the initial dataframe. I also can't think of a situation where I can use the pandas [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) method.

I know probably that the answer somehow lies behind the use of one the above methods or some combination of them but I am lacking the experience to think of it. I would appreciate some guidance/help. Thank you.

Comment: For same label, id and other attributes will always be same?\

Comment: Each id have always the same attributes but can have different label. For example, all attributes for id 123 are always the same (2 or less, category1, other_cat1) but label may not be the same in all observations.

Comment: I want to make the dataframe more concise. Now I have multiple identical records because attributes are all the same and mostly all ids belong to one label. For example I have 1233 rows where id is 123, the attributes are identical by default and the label is 2. I want to keep just one record of such observations. 
However, I may have an id which takes 3 different label values. In such case I want to keep these records. 
I think your answer covers my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First use `.groupby.transform` to add count column in the dataframe. Then drop the duplicate rows.

Use:

```
df['count'] = df.groupby('label')['id'].transform('count')
out = df.drop_duplicates(keep = 'first')
```

Output:

```
>>> out
    id            attr1      attr2       attr3  label  count
0  123        2 or less  category1  other_cat1      2      2
1   45  between 3 and 4  category3  other_cat3      7      2
3   76        5 or more  category4  other_cat4      9      1
5  123        2 or less  category1  other_cat1      1      1
```